# How can I convert this to a timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp

```
2014-03-06T00:50:49.000Z
```

How can I convert this to a timestamp in PHP?
It is given as a string:

```
$time = "2014-03-06T00:50:49.000Z";
```

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more OO way than the other answer...

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime("2014-03-06T00:50:49.000Z");
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```

I recommend this way because the DateTime class also has time manipulation and formatting methods. This is a class in 5.2.0+ , but there are implementations to mimic the DateTime class for earlier PHP versions.

Answer (score 3):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) can handle that date format:

```
echo strtotime("2014-03-06T00:50:49.000Z");
// 1394067049
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DIHwOC)